# How to control the position of the origin in ILPlotCube?

Tags: plot, charts, ilnumerics

When I plot data with ILPlotCube, the (0,0) origin is displayed with some offset (margin/gap) from the x and y axes. How can I remove this offset?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [ILLimits.Set](http://ilnumerics.net/apidoc/html/M_ILNumerics_Drawing_ILLimits_Set.htm)

For example:

```
 var start = -2;
 var sz = 6;

 ILArray<float> x = Enumerable.Range(start, sz).ToArray();
 var pc = new ILPlotCube(twoDMode: true)
 {
     new ILLinePlot(x)
 };

 pc.Limits.Set(new Vector3(0, start + sz - 1, 0), new Vector3(sz - 1, start, 0));
```

**Added (01/12/2016)**

My understanding was: you want to get rid of the space noted in the red circle? 
[Get rid of red circle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BnQTr.png)
Also changed the code a bit.

Comment: Thanks Roger. My data is negative and positive (x in your example). but at the moment when I plot the data, a point at  (0,0) coordinate of data is not match with (0,0) of x and Y axis ( there is a gap/Margin). Does above answer cover this or you are restricting data between 0 and 5 will be only displayed?

Comment: @james, please see the image in my update. To get rid of that space, you need to manually set the limits of your plot area. Maybe my understanding was wrong.

Comment: Thanks. your understand was correct. I wanted to get ride of red circle.